# How is used @RequestAttribute and @ModelAttribute annotation in this Spring MVC showcase example?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model, annotations

I am pretty new in Spring MVC.

In this period I am studying the [Spring MVC showcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase) example downlodable from STS dashboard.

I am having some problems understanding how Custom Resolvable Web Arguments are handled in this example.

In practice I have the following situation:

In my home.jsp view I have the following link:

```
<a id="customArg" class="textLink" href="<c:url value="/data/custom" />">Custom</a>
```

This link generate an HTTP Request towards the URL: **"/data/custom"**

The controller class that contains the method that handles this request has the following code:

```
@Controller
public class CustomArgumentController {

@ModelAttribute
void beforeInvokingHandlerMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute("foo", "bar");
}


@RequestMapping(value="/data/custom", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String custom(@RequestAttribute("foo") String foo) {
    return "Got 'foo' request attribute value '" + foo + "'";
}

 }
```

The method that handles this HTTP Request is **`custom()`**

So when the previous link is clicked the HTTP Request is handled by the custom method...

I am having problems understanding what the `@RequestAttribute` annotation.

I think that, in this case, it binds the request attribute named foo to a new `String foo` variable.

But... where is this attribute taken from? Is this variable taken by Spring?

Ok...my idea is that this request attribute is taken from a `HttpServletRequest` object...

I think this because, in this class, I have also have the `beforeInvokingHandlerMethod()` method that have a speacking name...so it seems that this method seta an attribute, that have `name=foo` and `value=bar`, inside an `HttpServletRequest` object...and then so the `custom()` method can use this value...

In fact my output is:

`Got 'foo' request attribute value 'bar'`

Why is the `beforeInvokingHandlerMethod()` called before the `custom()` method?

And why is the `beforeInvokingHandlerMethod()` annoted by `@ModelAttribute` annotation? What does this case mean?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in assumption of `@RequestAttribute`, it need not be set in `beforeInvokingHandlerMethod`. Assume you have a method mapped to `/data/init` which forwards request to `/data/custom`. In this case request attribute can be set in init method also.

> Why the beforeInvokingHandlerMethod() is called before the custom() method?
>
> And why the beforeInvokingHandlerMethod() is annoted by @ModelAttribute annotation? what means in this case?

you will get the reason here
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods

> An @ModelAttribute on a method indicates the purpose of that method is to add one or more model attributes. Such methods support the same argument types as @RequestMapping methods but cannot be mapped directly to requests. Instead @ModelAttribute methods in a controller are invoked before @RequestMapping methods, within the same controller.

Comment: mmm I have some difficulties to understand what exactly happen in the example tath I have post...

So reading what you have posted I have understand that if I have a command class with some method annoted by RequestMapping annotation and some other method annoted by ModelAttribute...these second type of method are invoked berfore the method annoted by RequestMapping...
So this method do something like inizialization

In my case what exactly happen? I store an attribute named foo in the passed HttpServletRequest...ok
Now is executed the custom() method that only extract the attribute value?

Comment: yes @ModelAttribute methods will be invoked first, before any request handlers in controller class. What you do in that method is set request attribute, which you can retrieve in your handler method.

Comment: `String custom(@RequestAttribute("foo") foo` this is a convenient method. Other wise you will have to write `String foo=(String) request.getAttribute("foo");`

Comment: mmm...ok...one last clarification about this thing:

So I am putting an attribute named "foo" that have value="bar" inside an HttpServletRequest object (that is an object created by the web container and that contains information about the request parameter and session information)

The clarification is about RequestAttribute annotation...doing:
RequestAttribute("foo") String foo

means that I am getting an attribute named foo by the HttpServletRequest? is it true? or from where?

Thank you

Andrea

Comment: spring is calling your method `custom()`. since it is annotated with @requestMapping spring will check for its parameters, type and populate them , before invoking it.

Comment: Ok, this is clear but the parameter is the HttpServletRequest object to which I added the attribute named "foo" in the other method because this object is a singleton created by my web container?