# How to set value to @RequestAttribute in Spring boot using postman or feign client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

I have method like this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/workflow-services/{service_id}/tickets",
  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<TicketIdResponse> createTicket(@PathVariable("service_id") String  serviceId,
  @RequestBody @Validated CreateTicketRequest request, @RequestAttribute Payload payload) {
log.info("Start create ticket [{}]", request);

TicketIdResponse response = ticketService.createTicket(serviceId, request, payload);

log.info("Create ticket response: {}", response);
return ResponseFactory.success(response);
```

}

so how to set value to @RequestAttribute Payload in postman or feign client

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

The @RequestAttribute annotation is usually used to retrieve data that is populated on the server-side but during the same HTTP request. For example, if you have used an interceptor, filter or possibly an aspect to populate the "payload" attribute then you should be able to access this using the @RequestAttribute annotation.

If you are looking to pass something from an external client (i.e via postman, curl or any other simple client) - @RequestAttribute is not the way forward.

Good references;
https://www.baeldung.com/whats-new-in-spring-4-3
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/request-attribute.html

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919307/how-is-used-requestattribute-and-modelattribute-annotation-in-this-spring-mvc) post may also help.

Answer (score 0):

you should set request attribute inside interceptor at serverside like shown below

```
    override fun preHandle(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, handler: Any): Boolean {
         request.setAttribute("requestInfo", RequestInfo(115639, 63643, 0, 266239512, applicationKey))
         true
}
```